# How can i delete all files using pattern matching and recursively through directories

Tags: find, filenames, rm

I have files in this format:

```
12.999.jpg
34.999.jpg
45.999.jpg
12.555.jpg
```

So, for example I wish to delete all files that have '999' as part of the file name.

But, these files can be in seperate directories but they wil all share the same root folder.

I know I can do this deleting folder using this syntax:

```
find <folder> -type d -empty -delete
```

So, transposing for files I have this:

```
find *.999.jpg -type f -delete
```

But this does not seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `man find`.

Something like:

```
find . -type f -name '*.999.jpg' -delete
```

will do the trick.

When first working with this use of `find`, omit the `-delete`, so `find` will simply list the files it finds.

Comment: that's so cool! thanks!